# The tag [constructor] disappears when editing question

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits

1. Pick a question with [constructor](/questions/tagged/constructor) tag (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constructor))
2. Click **edit** or **edit tags** if you have the privilege.
3. See if the question waiting for editing still has the [constructor](/questions/tagged/constructor) tag.

I tried with a dozen questions or so, every time it just disappears, why is it? Someone really hates constructors and wants to kick it away? Interestingly, the [destructor](/questions/tagged/destructor) tag is fine.

- Before edit:

[image: before edit]

- During edit:

[image: during edit]

As @hayd and @hims056 points out, it's also not in the tag box when editing, but [it's not blacklisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22627734/1009479) (10K user only).

[image: constructor tag]

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox Aurora 30.0a2. I wonder if a constructor is getting called or referenced by accident somewhere.

Comment: It's also not available if you write it in the tags box.

Comment: I doubted it is blacklisted. But [it isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22627734/1369235).

Comment: @hayd True, so whenever a question with tag [constructor] is edited,  the tag is gone forever. What a sad story.

Comment: Well, the bug is client side, the server [is returning correct data](http://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=constructor&newstyle=true&_=1395734363123) including the "constructor" tag itself.

Comment: I'm going to call it: whatever's populating that tag list just so happens to be calling `foo['constructor']`, and foo is an object or function, so it's returning an actual constructor function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.3.24.2092` on meta and rev`2014.3.24.1492` on sites.

Comment: `if (existing[data[i].Name] === true) continue; // don't render existing tags` Fixed using my suggestion. Muahahahaha.

Comment: @michaelb958 tnx for spoiling the fun :)

Answer (score 8):

Jonathan Hobbs (in the comments) called correctly; this is a collision with a property of a raw JS object.

The tag editor uses functionality in [`tageditornew.en.js` (link)](http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/tageditornew.en.js) for its autocompletion. Step one is to get the appropriate values from the server. This returns JSON starting with

```
[{"Name":"constructor","Synonyms":"constructors","Count":7280,"Excerpt":"A special type of subroutine called at the creation of an object."},...
```

(the `...` being my addition). So the tag is making its merry way down from the server.

Step two is to check if that tag is already in use. The critical code:

```
function showTagSuggestions(data, typed) {
    // ...
    var existing = {};
    editor.find('.post-tag').each(function () { existing[$(this).text()] = true; });
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (existing[data[i].Name]) continue; // don't render existing tags
```

Note the use of a bare object to hold already-used tags.

## Console

> ```
> >>> ({}).constructor
> Object()
> ```

This attribute conflicts, as predicted, with the `constructor` tag, so step three (render the tag and add it to the list of suggestions) is skipped, as "the tag is already in use" (except it isn't; it just conflicts with a JS property).

That is a really dumb comparison in the above code; I suggest changing it to

```
if (existing[data[i].Name] === true) continue;
```

or using some other string storage mechanism that doesn't have this conflict potential.